# Netbeans active packaging on ubuntu - dpkg not found

Tags: java, netbeans, packaging, ubuntu-14.04, dpkg

I want to package my java application as a Debian Package. I'm using the build-in native packager of netbeans(8.0.1) for Deb-Packages

Following output after packing:
Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "command" (in directory

> "/home/testuser/Songs"): error=2, No such file or directory
>   /home/testuser/Songs/nbproject/jfx-impl.xml:3415: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /home/testuser/Songs/nbproject/jfx-impl.xml:3584: Error:
>   JavaFX native packager requires Debian Packager tools to create DEB package, but dpkg could not be found.
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

I have installed the dpkg-dev with apt-get. the $PATH variable contains /usr/bin

I don't know how to fix that problem. anyone has an idea why netbeans does not find dpkg?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem overriding the target -check-dpkg-presence define in nbproject/jfx-impl.xml.

The original target looks for "command" file in the project folder.
The row check the real path of dpkg.
Running command -v dpkg you get /usr/bin/dpkg.

This is the same beavoiur you get if you try the line

which dpkg    ==> /usr/bin/dpkg

So i do this in build.xml

```
<target name="-check-dpkg-presence" depends="-check-native-bundling-type" if="need.dpkg.presence">
        <local name="exec.which.dpkg.result"/>
        <local name="exec.which.dpkg.output"/>
        <exec executable="which" failifexecutionfails="false" failonerror="false" resultproperty="exec.which.dpkg.result" outputproperty="exec.which.dpkg.output">
            <arg line="dpkg"/>
        </exec>
        <condition property="missing.dpkg">
            <not><and>
                <isset property="exec.which.dpkg.result"/>
                <equals arg1="${exec.which.dpkg.result}" arg2="0"/>
                <isset property="exec.which.dpkg.output"/>
                <not><equals arg1="${exec.which.dpkg.output}" arg2=""/></not>
            </and></not>
        </condition>
    </target>
```

I change the attribute  (executable='which') and the line attribute of the arg tag.

And it works.

Answer (score 2):

If you try running `ant -v build-native` in your project directory, you'll see the error. The ant build script created by NetBeans is trying to run `command dpkg ...` to build the package, but since "command" is a built-in shell command in /bin/bash, the test for "command" in your PATH fails.

I created a shell script named "command" in my local path with this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
command $@
```

which works fine.

Comment: This worked fine for me as well. Still, as of roughly a year later one would think Oracle would, if not fix the issue, document it in the readme.

Comment: Can u please explain local means !